# Postgresql - Select rows where 4 day before

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this data in userBuyTable

```
+-------+------------+
|  ID   |    Date    |
+-------+------------+
| 11111 | 2019-11-02 |
| 11111 | 2019-11-05 |
| 22222 | 2019-11-22 |
| 33333 | 2019-11-22 |
| 33333 | 2019-11-23 |
+-------+------------+
```

I want to where ID that have data before 4 day like this

```
+-------+------------+
|  ID   |    Date    |
+-------+------------+
| 11111 | 2019-11-02 |
| 11111 | 2019-11-05 |
+-------+------------+
```

(2019-11-05 - 2019-11-02) = 3

```
+-------+------------+
|  ID   |    Date    |
+-------+------------+
| 33333 | 2019-11-22 |
| 33333 | 2019-11-23 |
+-------+------------+
```

(2019-11-23 - 2019-11-22 ) = 1

this is the expected result

```
+-------+------------+
|  ID   |    Date    |
+-------+------------+
| 11111 | 2019-11-05 |
| 33333 | 2019-11-23 |
+-------+------------+
```

I try to select

```
select 
ID
,(select ID from userBuyTable ubtIn where ubtIn.ID = ubt.ID and (ubt.Date - ubtIn.Date)<4 ) 
from userBuyTable ubt where ubt.Date between '2019-11-01' and '2019-11-30'
```

Comment: should each date be compared against all other rows?

Comment: yes compared against all other rows

Answer (score 1):

With `EXISTS`:

```
select u.* from userBuyTable u
where u."Date" between '2019-11-01' and '2019-11-30'
and exists (
  select 1 from userBuyTable
  where u."Date" > "Date" and u."Date" - "Date" < 4 
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8fUzbQia2QhKZwGFbwwosg/0).

If you are interested only for rows with the same `ID` then use this:

```
select u.* from userBuyTable u
where u."Date" between '2019-11-01' and '2019-11-30'
and exists (
  select 1 from userBuyTable
  where u."ID" = "ID" and u."Date" > "Date" and u."Date" - "Date" < 4 
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8fUzbQia2QhKZwGFbwwosg/1).
Results:

```
| ID    | Date       |
| ----- | ---------- |
| 11111 | 2019-11-05 |
| 33333 | 2019-11-23 |
```

Answer (score 1):

I would simply use `lag()` and `lead()` if you want the original rows:

```
select ubt.*
from (select ubt.*,
             lag(date) over (partition by id order by date) as prev_date,
             lead(date) over (partition by id order by date) as next_date
      from userBuyTable ubt
     ) ubt
where (prev_date > date - 4 * interval '1 day') or
      (next_date < date + 4 * interval '1 day');
```

If you just want the most recent row that matches the condition, then either:

```
select ubt.*
from (select ubt.*,
             lag(date) over (partition by id order by date) as prev_date
      from userBuyTable ubt
     ) ubt
where prev_date > date - 4 * interval '1 day';
```

or:

```
select ubt.id, max(ubt.date)
from userBuyTable ubt
where exists (select 1
              from userBuyTable ubt2
              where ubt2.id = ubt.id and ubt2.date > date - 4 * interval '1 day'
             )
group by ubt.id;
```